# Override reveal.js in R Markdown presentation

Tags: css, r, rstudio, r-markdown, reveal.js

I'm trying to bring together a reveal-js presentation i rmarkdown but is having trouble overriding the default css theme. I would like to remove border from my plot images. According to the documentation this should work:

[image: Custom-css]

But it doesn't, which I guess is because this override isn't more specific. But my problem is my usual ways of increasing specificity doesn't work either:

````
## Slide with Plot
<section class = "no-border">
```{r pressure}
plot(pressure)
```
</section>
````

This is the YAML-header:

```
title: "Title"
author: "..."
date: '`r paste(format(Sys.Date(),"%d")," ", mymonths[sys.man], ", ",
                format(Sys.Date(),"%Y"), sep = "")`'
output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    incremental: true
    includes:
      in_header: slidy_bootstrap_header.html
      css: slidyStandard.css
```

And this is the css-override:

```
section.no-border > img {
  background:none; 
  border:none; 
  box-shadow:none;
 }
```

Anybody that knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the indentation in the YAML is correct? Have you tried adding `!important` to your CSS classes?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer I hope so, no errors but that doesn't mean anything ofc, added it as well. Edit: tried !Important, didn't work either

Comment: For completeness you could also add your CSS styles for `.no-border` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realised that I had put the custom-css in the wrong place in my YAML-header. Hence, it didn't work.

Below is reproducible code with custom css:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    css: custom2.css
---

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

## Slide with R Code and Output

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

## Slide with Plot

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

And the css:

```
.reveal section img {
  margin: 15px 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be, that your `<section>` tag is not being wrapped around the source code and its output. What you could do is to go with jQuery:

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "..."
output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    incremental: true
    includes:
      css: slidyStandard.css
---

<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add class to img elements -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $elms = $('p > img');
  $elms.addClass('no-border');
});
</script>

<!-- define no-border class -->
<style>
.no-border {
  border: 0px !important;
}
</style>

```{r pressure}
plot(pressure)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Should I add it in the head (in_header:) or before body (before_body:)?

Comment: You could just add it at right after the YAML block and before your first slide.

Comment: Ok - thx! It's inserted into the html but it doesn't execute, it seems, because the img-tags are un-altered.

Comment: That is weird. I added a picture to show you the result I get. I also added the full content of the Rmd. The big black border around the plot is gone (some shadow remains).

Comment: Yeah - weird but the error seems to be in my full presentation, because I get your code to work as well... Probably something that overrides the override... :) Thx!